# Python argparse empty

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, argparse

I'm coding a script that I need to execute with the following line (this is a compulsory request for an assignment).

```
python3 my_program.py method_name
```

Where method_name is the name of the algorithm in the script that I want to run in this execution. To do this I'm using argparse like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=None)
parser.add_argument('--method',  type=str, help='Method')
    
args = parser.parse_args([])
```

If I print the args this is the result:

```
print(args)
```

```
Namespace(method=None)
```

So apparently args is empty even it seems like it read the execution line correctly, because I did not get any error message. Why is my code not reading the name of the method? Should I be using a different method than argparse to read the method_name with the requested line? Or am I using argparse wrong?

Thank you! :)

Comment: With that parser definition you should be using "python3 my_program.py --method aname", and as `parse_args()` to parse that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're explicitly passing an empty `list` to `.parse_args()`.  Just use:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

to capture the passed `--method` into the `argparse.Namespace`.

---

Detail: if you look at the [argparse.py code in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L1824), you'll see the following:

```py
    def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        if args is None:
            # args default to the system args
            args = _sys.argv[1:]
        else:
            # make sure that args are mutable
            args = list(args)
```

You want the `if args is None` branch (that's the implicit with `parse_args()`), which will actually capture `sys.argv[:1]`, e.g. the options passed on the command line.